# SQL request duplicate lines with different values

Tags: sql

I have this table in my database:

| ID | Name | Quarter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Martin | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | Smith | 1 | 110 |
| 3 | Doe | 1 | 115 |
| 4 | Martin | 2 | 110 |
| 5 | Smith | 2 | 110 |
| 6 | Doe | 2 | 115 |
| 7 | Martin | 2 | 115 |
| 8 | Smith | 2 | 110 |
| 9 | Doe | 2 | 115 |
| 10 | Martin | 3 | 120 |
| 11 | Smith | 3 | 115 |
| 12 | Doe | 3 | 115 |

I would like to extract The value for each Quarter by Name. As the table is a dump from other SQL inserts, it may be possible that sometimes quarters are repeated and the values may or not changed ( The names will stay the same), so I need the latest data for that Quarter, which will be the ones with the biggest ids.

For example, in the table there are duplicate values for Quarter 2. So I would need the values for Quarter 1 and 3 and also the data for Quarter 2 which I highlighted in red.

I am lost on how to do that in a single query, so thanks much in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS? Look into the `row_number()` function. Also, replace images with formatted table for best results.

Comment: See how I made the table? Always do it that way from now on. Using an image for this instead of formatted text hurts your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: OK @Joel Coehoorn. Apologies for the poor formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DBMS supports it, use the `row_number` function.

```
create table table1 (
  id integer, 
  name varchar(20), 
  quarter integer, 
  value integer
  );
  
insert into table1 values 
(1, 'A', 1, 100), 
(2, 'B', 1, 110), 
(3, 'C', 1, 115), 
(4, 'A', 2, 110), 
(5, 'B', 2, 110), 
(6, 'C', 2, 115), 
(7, 'A', 2, 115), 
(8, 'B', 2, 110), 
(9, 'C', 2, 115), 
(10, 'A', 3, 120), 
(11, 'B', 3, 115), 
(12, 'C', 3, 115);
```

---

```
select id, name, quarter, value
from (
    select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by name, quarter order by id desc) as rn 
    from table1
 )z
where rn = 1
order by quarter, name;
```

| id | name | quarter | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | B | 1 | 110 |
| 3 | C | 1 | 115 |
| 7 | A | 2 | 115 |
| 8 | B | 2 | 110 |
| 9 | C | 2 | 115 |
| 10 | A | 3 | 120 |
| 11 | B | 3 | 115 |
| 12 | C | 3 | 115 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/meZzupfcm7b7LGRomCPo47/0)

Comment: I just want to suggest small changes it should be "order by id;" instead of "order by quarter, name;" at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, Name, Quarter, value
  from tablename
 where id = (select id
               from tablename 
              where Quarter = '1'
              order by id desc
              limit 1) 
    OR id = (select id
               from tablename
              where Quarter = '2'
              order by id desc 
              limit 1) 
    OR id = (select id
               from tablename
              where Quarter = '3'
              order by id desc
              limit 1) 
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: This is inefficient and provides the wrong results.

Comment: Base on your question or query to my understanding you are looking for a way to get the last row id for quarter 1,2,3 displaying the records with there column, no matter how wrong the answer is to you, you don't use does words in the public @isolated and for us to know you have gotten the solution share Incase other people are facing the same problem or issue.